# get comment data using comment id

Tags: php, comments

I am using the `get_comments()` function which works well if I give it any array of parameters except if I give the following array:

```
$defaults = array('ID' => $comment_id); 

$com=get_comments($defaults );
```

The resulting array contains all data for all comments of  my website.  I want  to get only the data of the comment with id = $comment_id.

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sorry for wasting your time
I think there is a simple function that can do this:

```
<?php
$defaults = $comment_id; 
$com= get_comment($defaults ); ?>
```